# How to initialize a $n$ qubit system in this specific state

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, initialization

Basically, I have $2n$ qubits and I want to initialize them in the state $\frac{|\psi\rangle}{\lVert |\psi\rangle \rVert}$ where
$$|\psi \rangle = \sum_{\mathrm{w}\in \{0,1\}^n}|\mathrm{w}\mathrm{w}\rangle$$
I know how to do it naively in Qiskit and for my purpose, this is not that bad (i.e I have $\log n$ qubits so the whole process will take $O(n^2)$ steps) but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. I'm new to Quantum Computing so I'm sorry if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate an equal superposition on the first $n$ qubits using $H^{\otimes n}$, then use $n$ CNOT gates to get the desired state:

[image]

This circuit has a depth of $2$

Answer (score 1):

@Ergetta.Thula's answer is complete. I just thought to add a little bit more to this discussion.

In general, the following circuit takes the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes 2N}$ to the state $\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i |b_i \rangle |b_i \rangle$ where we also have that
$\big(W \otimes I^{\otimes N} \big)|0\rangle^{\otimes 2N} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^N} \lambda_i |b_i\rangle |0\rangle^{\otimes N}$. Note $|b_i\rangle$ are the computational basis states. That is, $|b_i \rangle \in \{0,1\}^{ N}$.

[image]

If we add two other unitaries, says $U, V$ to system $A$ and $B$, then we can represent any arbitrary state $|\Psi \rangle$ of an $N + N$ qubit system. That is:

[image]

$$ |\Psi \rangle = (U \otimes V) \sum_{i=1}^{2^N} \lambda_i |b_i\rangle \otimes |b_i\rangle $$

Comment: There seem to be some problem with formatting in the second paragraph. Also, regarding your last paragraph. Is there a situation where I want to use the aforementioned  construction ($2N$ qubits with $N$ CNOTs and operators $U,V$) instead of some other arbitrary circuit? Also, where can I find a more formal reference for that ?

Comment: Also since we already have $N$ CNOTs  shouldn't be there any condition on $U$ and $V$? Like $U $and $V$ are comprised of 1 qbit gates or something.